# Linux using pkill to kill by process name for a specific user

Tags: linux, bash, pkill

I have a bash script where I run the pkill command to kill running processes. I have the username param defined as follows:

```
username=$(whoami)
```

I want to be able to kill processes based on the process name but also kill them only for the current user.This script will be used by other users as well, hence setting the username param so that the script works for them also.

Can any one tell me how I would go about that?
Im trying the following:

```
pkill -f -U $username | "testProcess"
```

is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for killing a process called exactly `testProcess` for the current user is

```bash
pkill -x -U "$(id -u)" testProcess
```

I'm u-ing `id -u` rather than `whoami` out of habit and because `id` is more commonly used in scripts than `whoami` is. You could instead use a pre-existing variable such as `$USER` or `$LOGNAME` or similar, depending on the environment (but remember to double-quote the expansion, whatever you use).

If you use `-f`, the pattern, which is interpreted as a regular expression, will be matched against the command line of all processes, not just the command names.  With `-x`, the pattern is required to match the complete string (in the case above, the name of the process must be precisely `testProcess` and not, e.g., `atestProcess2`; combining `-x` with `-f` requires a match of the complete command line).

Your attempted command appears to want to pass the output of `pkill` to a command called `testProcess`.  This is likely not what you want.

Note that a non-root user may not signal other users' processes, so unless the user is root, the `-U` option and its option-argument is not strictly required (unless you want to avoid "Operation not permitted" errors).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! so in this case if I wanted to be able to find a string pattern for the process name, rather than the exact process name is that doable?

Comment: @kasssia I don't quite know what you mean by "find a string pattern".  If you want to match a pattern against only the process name, don't use `-f`.  If you want the pattern to match substrings in the process name, don't use `-x`.

Comment: Yes so I mean if "testProcess" is not the whole process name just the begining, but its enough for us to match on then the syntax  is: pkill -U "$(id -u)" "testProcess" ?

Comment: @kasssia Yes, that command (in your comment) will signal any process whose command name contains the string `testProcess`, belonging to the current user.